# Javascript operators

Tags: javascript, operators

I am using a "LightenDarkenColor" function in my script and never really paid much attention to it until now and I noticed some operations and I had no idea what they were doing. I had actually never seen them before.

Those operators are `>>` and `&`. I also noticed that the function doesn't work in Firefox.

The function:

```
function LightenDarkenColor(color, percent) {

        var num = parseInt(color,16),
            amt = Math.round(2.55 * percent),
            R   = (num >> 16) + amt,
            B   = (num >> 8 & 0x00FF) + amt,
            G   = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;

        return (0x1000000 + (R<255?R<1?0:R:255)*0x10000 + (B<255?B<1?0:B:255)*0x100 + (G<255?G<1?0:G:255)).toString(16).slice(1);

}
```

What exactly are the operators and how do they work?

Comment: What is [shift right and bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: Googling `Javascript  operators` would have gotten  you the answer.

Comment: In case you were wondering, the code generates a hexadecimal colour representation of a lighter or darker colour given an existing colour and its lightness (0-100%)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Possibly, though it would have been after all the pages on basic operators like `==`, `===`, `&&` and all that.

Comment: Scratch that, MDN happened to be the 2nd link xD

Comment: First link, even. (For me, since I'm blocking w3schools links)

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work on Firefox? I seems to work just fine here `alert(LightenDarkenColor('667788', 10));` alerts 8091a2

Comment: @FrancescoMM Where I was using it, it didn't work however I had errors but since fixing them Firefox works.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm blocking w3schools too. MDN was the second for me.

Comment: @Cerbrus indeed the other question is quite a duplicate of this. However that question does not have an accepted answer, so even if most of the answers look quite correct, and the question is trivial (googling it up), technically speaking that is still an unanswered question. That makes it still open and incomplete. So locking this up because it is a duplicate of an unanswered question may seem like actually locking out any possibilities of getting a complete answer. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine num is 227733 (= some mild dark green) and take

```
B   = (num >> 8 & 0x00FF)
```

num >> 8 will shift the number (move digits) to the right by 2 hex digits (4 bits per digit x 2=8) making it become:

227733 => 002277

then & 0x00FF will clear out all digits except the last two

002277 => 000077

and that is the component for green.

Hex 00FF is binary 0000000011111111 and `&` (binary AND) is the operation that will compare all bit pairs one by one and set all bits to zero unless both operand bits are 1s. So ANDing to zeroes will lead to zeroes, and ANDing to ones will give as result the same digits of the other operand: 1 & 1 => 1, 0 & 1=>0. Ones remain ones, zeroes remain zeroes. So AnyNumber & 0000000011111111 = the right part (lower 2 digits) of AnyNumber.

It is just the standard way of getting a number subpart. In this case the green component. Shift right to clear the lower bits, and &0000...1111 to clear the upper bits.

---

After it got all color components, it adds `amt` to all of them (`amt` positive=lighter) and at the end it crops the values

`R<255?R<1?0:R:255` means: `if less then 0 use 0, if more than 255 use 255`.

And finally restores the color as a single number (instead of *0x100 could have used R<<8 that is the opposite of >>8, instead of +, it could have used |, binary OR, to merge the components).

---

Note that the function uses B as the second component, assuming it is blue but in reality in RGB the second is Green. Yet the result is correct anyway (it would work whatever color components you used and however you named them)

Answer (score 1):

They're [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

`>>` is a bitwise *(Sign-propagating)* right shift,

`&` is a bitwise "and".

I could go into detail on what these operators do, but the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) has a good explanation and example for each operator. It would be counter-productive to copy those.